# Bluetooth peer to peer networking APIs iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bluetooth, p2p

G'Day programmers...I am planning to make an application which will be using peer to peer bluetooth connection between two different iOS device.

So my question is, is there any good tutorials which can guide me through?

Purpose is to send a stream of strings, like in chat application.

I want to learn so you may give me a direction something like,

> "Hey check this, XYZ API they intent to do what you are looking
>   for..." Or "There is a tutorial ..."

Thank you for any kind of help!

---

Research So far :

- Below link is about networking through wifi but not bluetooth

http://jens.mooseyard.com/2009/05/a-bonjour-chat-tutorial-for-iphone-developers/

- This link is promising, but could not find any relevant tutorial. Does anyone know a link which has tutorial for this?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GameKit is your best bet, in my opinion. The official docs are fantastic and should walk you through it just well, even though it's not a tutorial, per se.

Here are a couple though:

http://vivianaranha.com/apple-gamekit-bluetooth-integration-tutorial/

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/1954

and you can check out the source code of BeamIt!

http://arctouch.com/beamit/

Hope that helps.