# Transfer data between two iDevices with NO Internet

Tags: ios, file, transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bluetooth peer to peer networking APIs iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733338/bluetooth-peer-to-peer-networking-apis-ios)

I am building a Application where I need to transfer a file or string of information between two of applications. One on each iDevice. Each device has a separate application. Is there any way to do this (preferably without wifi or 3G or 4g required).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this question could help you:
[Bluetooth peer to peer networking APIs iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733338/bluetooth-peer-to-peer-networking-apis-ios)

Comment: Don't give that hint in the future, it is not allowed, as it is *noise* on the Stack Exchange network.  Continuing to do so may lead to further moderator action.